# Definir a prioridade de threads em C++11

Tags: linux, c++, thread, c++11

No programa que estou desenvolvendo tenho dois std::threads que estão
sempre ativos durante toda a vida do programa. No entanto, considero
que a função de um deles é de menor importância e gostaria de alterar 
a prioridade deles.

Dei uma olhada na documentação e não achei nenhuma função que defina 
a prioridade do std::thread.

Minha duvida é: como defino a prioridade de um std::thread? É possível ou
o próprio sistema operacional se encarrega de definir isso em tempo de execução?

Obs: O programa só rodará em Linux (Debian), por isso, não há necessidade de 
portabilidade com Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não há nenhuma forma de alterar a prioridade de um `std::thread` no C++11 ou no C++14. A única forma de fazer isso seria pelo uso de funções do linux (não portável). Obtenha um identificador nativo com o [`std::thread::native_handle()`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) e o use com a função [`pthread_setschedparam`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html). Um exemplo (retirado da primeira referência):

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>
#include <pthread.h>

std::mutex iomutex;
void f(int num)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    sched_param sch;
    int policy; 
    pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &policy, &sch);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(iomutex);
    std::cout << "Thread " << num << " executando na prioridade "
              << sch.sched_priority << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(f, 1), t2(f, 2);

    sched_param sch;
    int policy; 
    pthread_getschedparam(t1.native_handle(), &policy, &sch);
    sch.sched_priority = 20;
    if (pthread_setschedparam(t1.native_handle(), SCHED_FIFO, &sch)) {
        std::cout << "setschedparam falhou: " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
    }

    t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

No Windows a mesma ideia pode ser aplicada com a [`SetThreadPriority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18884946/1606920) a biblioteca padrão do C++11 não presta suporte padrão para o controle de prioridade de threads. (O autor ainda acredita que não isso não mudará no C++14)
Nessa mesma resposta ele cita um comando que funciona em sistemas que sigam as normas [POSIX](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX):

> `pthread_setschedparam(thread.native_handle(), politica, {prioridade});`

Como você quer só para linux, esse método deve resolver seu problema. Existem ainda alguns pontos relevantes a serem levados em conta.

### A política padrão de threads do Linux tem prioridade dinâmica

Geralmente, quando você inicia uma thread, o Linux coloca a política `SCHED_OTHER`, como é visto [nessa resposta da SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649281/how-to-increase-thread-priority-in-pthreads).
Nessa mesma resposta, ele coloca os tipos de política que podem ser adotadas para o sistema de thread e qual a prioridade mínima e a máxima:

> `SCHED_FIFO`: Esquema de fila, primeira a entrar, é o primeiro a sair. (1/99)
>
> `SCHED_RR`: Esquema de política [round-robin](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin). (1/99)

Onde a prioridade está da seguinte forma (min/máx). Eu optei por colocar as políticas que tinha prioridade. Apesar de eu ler nos comentários que o `SCHED_OTHER` pode [oferecer um certo nível de controle de prioridade](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Priorities_and_policies.html), ele é definido pelo próprio sistema conforme o comportamento da thread, o que você pode fazer é dar "uma dica da importância da thread", setando sua prioridade como muito alta (-20) ou muito baixa (19).

### Políticas para troca de threads

Threads com as políticas `SCHED_RR` ou `SCHED_FIFO` serão trocadas se um dos dois eventos acontecerem, ainda segundo esse [link](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Priorities_and_policies.html):

> - Uma thread é posta para dormir (`sleep`) ou passa a esperar um evento
> - Uma thread de tempo real de prioridade maior está pronta para rodar

Esses pontos devem ser levados em conta quando você for implementar as suas threads.

### Dito isso, vamos ao nosso exemplo:

[Exemplo retirado do cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle):

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>
#include <pthread.h>

std::mutex iomutex;
void f(int num) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

   sched_param sch;
   int policy; 
   pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &policy, &sch);
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(iomutex);
   std::cout << "Thread " << num << " esta executando com prioridade "
             << sch.sched_priority << '\n';
}

int main(){
    //A thread 2 será uma thread padrão
    std::thread t1(f, 1), t2(f, 2);

    sched_param sch;
    int policy; 
    pthread_getschedparam(t1.native_handle(), &policy, &sch);
    sch.sched_priority = 20;
    //Nessa linha ele seta a política e a prioridade da thread 1
    if(pthread_setschedparam(t1.native_handle(), SCHED_FIFO, &sch)) {
        std::cout << "Falha para utilizar setschedparam: " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
    }

    t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

Apesar de tudo, eu fiquei com uma dúvida, talvez pelo meu desconhecimento de como sistemas POSIX tratam as prioridades de threads, mas, pelo que o exemplo coloca como saída, threads com valores **mais altos** de prioridade, tem prioridade **menor**.

Saída do exemplo:

```
Thread 2 esta executando com prioridade 0
Thread 1 esta executando com prioridade 20
```

Answer (score 1):

A forma de fazer isso envolve a obtenção de uma handle para a implementação nativa da thread. Um exemplo de uso da função std::thread::native_handle está descrito em http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle.